# Launch ADB command from PHP with script shell

Tags: php, android, shell, mamp, adb

I'm coding a web app which allows users to install android application on their android smartphone (plug with USB).

There is my PHP script (running in localhost with MAMP server) :

```
echo exec('./myscript.sh '.$apkName);
```

And there is my shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo test
adb install ./$1
```

But I think, there is a right problem to execute adb command, that I don't understand, because I set the adb in chmod 777...

The command line 'echo test' workd perfectly but not the adb command.

Could you enlight me for this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: May be as u don't have sdk tools on the php server

Comment: Do you intend for your users to run your PHP script locally or do you expect this to work over the web in production?

Answer (score 0):

try `adb -d install <My APK Path>/<My APK Name>.apk`